# How to append elements to a list in python

Tags: python

```
totalNum = int(input("No of people?"))
for i in range(1,totalNum+1):

    name_list = []
    name = input("Name?")
    name_list.append(name)
print(name_list)
```

In the end, when I tried to print all the elements in the list, only the last element was printed.

Comment: You are creating a new list in every iteration

Comment: Define name_list = [] before the for.

Comment: You could use `range(totalNum)` in place of `range(1,totalNum+1)`. You will have a moment of epiphany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the list `name_list = []` outside the loop, not every time within the loop:

Ps. with a little change to your `range()`:

```
name_list = []

totalNum = int(input("No of people?"))
for i in range(totalNum):   
    name = input("Name?")
    name_list.append(name)
print(name_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are re-initializing the list in every iteration and hence once the loop is done the last list is printed.

Here is the fixed version of the code

```
totalNum = int(input("No of people?"))
name_list = []
for _ in range(totalNum):
    name = input("Name?")
    name_list.append(name)
print(name_list)
```

Also note the use of `_` here, it is a special throw away variable in python which you use if just need a dummy variable to loop over a sequence.

Also you don't need to initialize the `range` like `range(1,totalNum+1)`, since python sequences always start from 0 you can do `range(totalNum)`.